# Create Matrix indexing with array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have the following problem:

```
 i  j  x  y
-1 -1 -1 -1 
-1  0 -1  0
-1  1 -1  1
 0 -1  0 -1 
 0  0  0  0 
 0  1  0  1
 .
 . 
 . 
 1  1  1  1
```

I am trying to arrange an array that has the exact form (the i j give the grid postion xy the coordinates at that position)

Here is what I tried:

```
SIZE=input("Enter Size of Grid: ")

**def Grid():**
size=SIZE
i=[]
j=[]
k=size
n=size
m=size

while m in range(-size,size+1):
    j0=int(k)
    j=np.append(j,j0)
    i0=int(n)
    i=np.append(i,i0)
    if k == -size:
        n=n-1
    k=k-1
    m=m-1



i=i*-1
j=j*-1

print("j is: ",j)
print("i is: ",i)
```

Grid()

Response is:

```
Enter Size of Grid: 5
j is:  [-5. -4. -3. -2. -1. -0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
i is:  [-5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5.]
```

But I simply havent found a way to repeat this for i=-4-4-4-4-4-4-4....:(

Comment: I don't understand your input: i, j are exactly the same as x, y. If i, j are supposed to be indices (like numpy.indices), then I would have expected them to start at 0, not contain a -1.

Comment: `while m in range(-size,size+1):`: are you sure you don't want to replace that with an inverted for-loop, `for m in range(size, -size-1, -1)`?

Comment: well its how the program that im trying to emulate is giving out grid. Just think of it as a grid that starts with at the left bottom corner with (-n,-n), than goes rightwards (-n,-n+1) .... (-n,n), scans upwards. 
Each position is assigned the value (x_n,y_n). For simplification I just put the values (-1-1) as (x_-n, y_-n)

Comment: Inverting doesn't change much, i still get
                      j is:  [-5. -4. -3. -2. -1. -0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
                       i is:  [-5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5.]
as output , which is what I want! But now do that another elven times so that i get:
        j is:  [-5. -4. -3. -2. -1. -0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
               [-5. -4. -3. -2. -1. -0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
        i is:  [-5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5. -5.]
               [-4  -4  -4  -4   -4  -4  -4  -4  -4  -4 -4]